# I'm experiencing Oracle join problems with this join

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I'm trying to do this join but it says it is not properly ended any ideas

```
SELECT      
    first_name, last_name, MAIL_COUNTRY_ID, EMAIL
FROM        
    people, PUBAUTHOR_PEOPLE 
WHERE       
    people.people_id = PUBAUTHOR_PEOPLE.people_id 
JOIN 

select country
from countries
where country c on c.country_id = p.coutry_id
```

Comment: Are you really intending to mix the SQL 99 join syntax with the old style syntax?  You would almost certainly want to just use the SQL 99 syntax (`a join b on (a.id = b.id)`) or to just use the old-style join syntax where you list tables in the `FROM` clause and specify the join predicates in the `WHERE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query :

```
SELECT      
  first_name, last_name, countries.country, email
FROM        
  people 
JOIN pubauthor_people ON
  People.people_id = pubauthor_people.people_id 
JOIN countries ON 
   countries.country_id = people.mail_country_id
```

Comment: im trying to get the country from the country id in countrys and join it to pub-AUTHORPEOPLE

Comment: @user3841039 what is the column that links PUBAUTHOR_PEOPLE to Country ? Do you have country_id in PUBAUTHOR_PEOPLE ?

Comment: COUNTRY_ID connects from people to countries and people-id connects pubauthor_people to people

Comment: @user3841039 so my query should work, what else do you need ? Just use the columns in the table country it is already well joined.

Comment: @user3841039 what are the fields in the table Country you need ?

Comment: the table is countries not country, and the columns are                                FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME COUNTRY_ID EMAIL and where it says country_id i want it to be the country that corresponds with that country code

Comment: added mail_ in front of country_id

Comment: @user3841039 Did it work ? If so please upvote and accept answer, it not please provide more info (as table structures).

Comment: thanks, it worked if i need any thing else ill ask you i up voted your answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58701/discussion-between-user3841039-and-simon).

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid mix standards and do that this way:

```
select  first_name, last_name, MAIL_COUNTRY_ID, EMAIL, countries.country   
FROM people   
join PUBAUTHOR_PEOPLE on people.people_id = PUBAUTHOR_PEOPLE.people_id  
JOIN countries  on countries.country_id = PEOPLE.country_id
```

Comment: im trying to get the country from the country id in countrys and join it to pub-AUTHORPEOPLE

Comment: @user3841039 Now I see what you mean, if in country table you have got country field updated answer should work for you

Comment: the table is countries not country, and the columns are FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME COUNTRY_ID EMAIL and where it says country_id i want it to be the country that corresponds with that country code –

Comment: I've changed to countries, but 2nd part of your description isn't clear for me. Can you include tables strucktures?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58700/discussion-between-user3841039-and-parado).